# How to apply PCA but keep original attributes?

Tags: weka, pca

I am using Weka Explorer to apply PCA to my data. There are 4 columns: R, G, B (representing color values in a pixel) and id (nominal, representing the class of the pixel). I want PCA to produce a single variable (call it V) that combines the information in R, G, B. I then want to perform some analysis (clustering) on V and visualize the results wrt id.

If I load my data and select `PrincipalComponent` in the Preprocess tab, it applies PCA, but to all of the attributes. So "id" becomes incorporated which produces nonsense results. It also replaces my original data with the principal components produced. I would like to, instead, *keep* my original attributes (especially "id") and have the principal component become additional attributes. Is this possible in Weka Explorer?

Answer (score 0):

This does what you want, but it keeps only the "ID" column, not the others.

There's a second PCA feature in the "Select Attributes" tab. It can be used as a filter in the "Preprocess" tab.

To do so, use the "Supervised Attribute Filter" named `AttributeSelection` and configure it analoguous to the screenshots below (markers 1,2,3). I have used a "CPU with vendor" arff datafile which does not really contain a unique "ID" attribute but a similar string attribute "vendor" in the first column  (5). Select "vendor"/ID as the new class attribute (6). Before doing so I had to remove the eighth attribute "class" (4) - maybe this step is optional for you. Now only 7 attributes are left. Click "Apply" (7).

[image: Screenshot 1]

By default PCA uses the first 5 principal components to determine the new transformed values.

See second screenshot. After the PCA calculation, Column "vendor" (1) has moved to the last position but has *not* been used in the PCA calculation of the 5 new columns (2). The transformed values based on 5 principal components - the "A" parameter (3)- can be seen in  the column list (1)

[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: Thanks for this answer! Unfortunately I wasn't able to " configure `AttributeSelection` "analoguous to the screenshots below (markers 1,2,3)" - could you please edit to explain it a bit?

Comment: @wassinger You must click on the Bold typeface "AttributeSelection" and then in the new dialog choose a new "evaluator" by clicking on "Choose" button, then select "PrincipalComponents", then Weka will force you to select "Ranker" then you'll get the string shown in my screenshot.